# What is the Controller in Django MVC?

Tags: mvc, terminology, django

Learning Django MVC and the way I thought of it is:

**Models**  are the database tables represented in Django as Python classes.
**Views** are the HTML returned from function in views.py.
**Controllers** are the actual functions themselves in views.py invoked from a HTTP request.

However I read on Wikipedia (at the time of writing):

> ... a regular-expression-based URL dispatcher ("Controller").

I would have thought the mapping of URLs to functions as routing - not the controller. But perhaps I am wrong - I guess I got my ideas because is ASP MVC the functions that handle the requests are contained in classes called Contollers...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your thoughts are not wrong. In MVC web-frameworks, people often speak of a Base Controller that performs the routing of a request to the actual Controller that handles the request.

This has come about because web frameworks generally have a single point where the request is received by the application and in pure MVC terms, this is where the job of the Controller starts.

---

The Django framework uses a non-idiomatic way of naming the parts of the MVC triad.

The mapping between Django names and the idiomatic terminology is:

```
Idiomatic term | Django term | Meaning
Model          | Model       | Contains all the business logic. At the very least the database access logic
View           | Template    | Responsible for generating the HTML and other UI
Controller     | View        | Contains the logic to tie the other parts together and to generate a response to a user request
```